# Why does a background with a lower z index show on top?

Tags: html, css

I have two overlapping backgrounds with absolute positioning and I'm trying to styling them such that they overlap and one is on top of the other. This is the CSS I wrote so far.

```css
.answered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.asked {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

h1{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.in-back {
  display: block;
  background: grey;
  z-index: -1;
}

.in-front {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  background: tan;
}
```

```html
<section class="history">
  <div class="asked">
    <h1 class="user-show-tab-title in-front">Questions</h1>
    <div>
      <ul class="question-index-false in-front">
        <li>
          <a class="question" href="http://localhost:3000/#questions/1">what train runs faster from wycoff?</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="question" href="http://localhost:3000/#questions/5">What is the history of the Block Island Ferry?</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="question" href="http://localhost:3000/#questions/78">What are the major human features in New York City?</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="question" href="http://localhost:3000/#questions/199">How much do greyhound bus tickets from California to Phoenix Arizona?</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="answered">
    <h1 class="user-show-tab-title in-back">Answers</h1>
    <div>
      <ul class="question-index-false in-back">
        <li>
          <a class="question" href="http://localhost:3000/#questions/129">What is the state bird of New York?</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

The grey keeps appearing on top of the tan even though its z-index is lower. I don't understand why.

Comment: Can you post all the css up to .history?

Comment: Please show enough code to replicate the problem. Your elements aren't absolutely positioned for one.

Comment: `z-index` will have **no effect** unless the elements have a position value of something **other** than `static`

Comment: ahh.. yeah the elements are absolute

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements are **not** positioned absolute, only their **parents** `.asked` and `.answered`. The `position` property is not inherited by child elements. Both `<ul>` have the default `position: static;` which is always applied unless you specify a different value for the `position` property. So adding `position: relative;` makes your z-index way work the way you expect.

```css
.answered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.asked {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
h1 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.in-back {
  display: block;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
.in-front {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  background: tan;
}
```

```html
<section class="history">
  <div class="asked">
    <h1 class="user-show-tab-title in-front">Questions</h1>
    <div>
      <ul class="question-index-false in-front">
        <li>
          <a class="question" href="http://localhost:3000/#questions/1">what train runs faster from wycoff?</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="question" href="http://localhost:3000/#questions/5">What is the history of the Block Island Ferry?</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="question" href="http://localhost:3000/#questions/78">What are the major human features in New York City?</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="question" href="http://localhost:3000/#questions/199">How much do greyhound bus tickets from California to Phoenix Arizona?</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="answered">
    <h1 class="user-show-tab-title in-back">Answers</h1>
    <div>
      <ul class="question-index-false in-back">
        <li>
          <a class="question" href="http://localhost:3000/#questions/129">What is the state bird of New York?</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I couldn't find any mention to that reading docs. thanks for the answer